# quisiera hacer una consulta y mostrar determinados datos de una tabla con mysql y php

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una tabla que es contratospendientes y otra que es usuario. EL campo usuario de la tabla usuario es igual al campo zv de la tabla contratospendientes.
La tabla contratos pendientes tiene muchos campos y uno de ellos es "anexoDistrEscal" y lod datos de este campo quiero que se muestren cuando el usuario y el zv sean iguales, el resto de datos que se vea en blanco.
Este es el códiog que he puesto, pero me muestra todos los datos de ese campo, aunque el zv y el usuario no coincidan:

```html
<td align="center"><?php
    $query = "select * from contratospendientes
    join usuarios on usuarios.usuario = contratospendientes.zv where '$zv' = '$usuario' ";
    $result=$mysqli->query($query,$conexion);
        if ($zv == $usuario){
            echo $d->anexoDistrEscal;}
        else{
            echo "";}
    ?>
 </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que quieres hacer es un JOIN entre tablas relacionándolas por el campo usuarios.usuario y contratospendientes.zv. Salvo que quieras un usuario concreto la forma de lograr el listado sería usando el siguiente query

```
   "select * from contratospendientes join usuarios on usuarios.usuario = contratospendientes.zv"
```

La condición where no es necesario, salvo que quieras un usuario concreto entonces podrías poner where usuarios.usuario = 'usuario concreto'